# Problem with Jquery, .getJSON in IE7-8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, getjson

I have a jquery script that creates image rollovers for counties in a state.  The script queries an XML document for county x/y coordinates and information, then displays this information when the county on the state image is hovered over. Additionally, a random county and county information is displayed until one of the counties is hovered on; Once the viewer hovers off of the county, the random display resumes.

The script works great in FireFox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer 7 - 8.   In IE, the random display works, but about 75% of the counties will not respond to the hover functionality, with apparently no pattern as to why they won't respond (as I said, they work great in other browsers).

```
    //____________________________________________________________________________________________________________ CONSTANTS
    var DATA_SOURCE       = '/CountyData.js';        // URL of the page that serves JSON county data

    var IMAGE_PATH        = '/images/counties/';     // Relative path to the county image folder

    var CSS_WRAPPER_CLASS = 'countyWrapper';        // CSS class to apply to each county's wrapper <div>
    var CSS_IMAGE_CLASS   = 'countyImage';          // CSS class to apply to <img> tags
    var CSS_INFO_CLASS    = 'countyInfo';           // CSS class to apply to info <div> tags

    var ROTATION_INTERVAL = 10;                     // seconds to show each random county while rotating


    //____________________________________________________________________________________________________ PRIVATE VARIABLES
    var _isHovering         = false;
    var _autoSelectedCounty = null;


    //______________________________________________________________________________________________________ FUN BEGINS HERE
    function highlightRandomCounty() {
        // only show a new county if we're not hovering over another one
        if (!_isHovering) {
            var children    = $('#map-holder').children('div');
            var randomIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * children.length);

            _autoSelectedCounty = $(children[randomIndex]).children('img')[0];

            hideAllCounties();
            showCounty(_autoSelectedCounty);
        }
    }

    function showCounty(countyImage) {
        $(countyImage).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
        $(countyImage).siblings().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
    }

    function hideCounty(countyImage) {
        $(countyImage).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 0);
        $(countyImage).siblings().animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 0);
    }

    function hideAllCounties() {
        var counties = $('#map-holder').children('div');

        for (var i = 0; i < counties.length; i++) {
            hideCounty($(counties[i]).children('img')[0]);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // show the pre-loader
        var preloader = document.createElement('div');
        $('#map-holder').append(preloader);
        $(preloader).attr('id', 'preloader');

        //testing var
        var countyCount = 1;
        $.getJSON(DATA_SOURCE, function(data) {

            $.each(data.countyData, function(i, item) {
                // create the container <div> and append it to the page
                var container = document.createElement('div');
                $('#map-holder').append(container);

                // configure the container
                $(container).attr('id', 'div' + item.data_county);
                $(container).attr('class', CSS_WRAPPER_CLASS);
                $(container).attr('style', 'left:'+ item.data_x + 'px; top:' + item.data_y + 'px;');


                // create the <img> and append it to the container
                var countyImage = document.createElement('img');
                $(container).append(countyImage); 

                // configure the image
                $(countyImage).attr('id', item.data_county + 'Image');
                $(countyImage).attr('class', CSS_IMAGE_CLASS);
                $(countyImage).attr('src', IMAGE_PATH + item.data_county_image + '.png');
                $(countyImage).load(function() {
                    // wait for the image loads before setting these properties
                    $(this).attr('width', countyImage.width);
                    $(this).attr('height', countyImage.height);
                });

                $(countyImage).hover(function() {

                    _isHovering = true;
                    hideCounty(_autoSelectedCounty);
                    showCounty($(this));
                },

                function() {
                    _isHovering = false;
                    hideCounty($(this));
                });

                $(countyImage).click(function() {
                    window.location.href =  item.factsLink;
                });

                // create the info <div> and append it to the container
                var countyInfo = document.createElement('div');
                $(container).append(countyInfo);
                $(countyInfo).attr('id', item.data_county + 'Info');
                $(countyInfo).attr('class', CSS_INFO_CLASS);

                // Handle county naming exceptions
                var countyName = item.data_county.toUpperCase();
                if (countyName == 'SAINTJOYVILLE') {
                    countyName = 'ST. JOYVILLE';
                } else {
                    if (countyName.indexOf("SAINT") > -1) {
                        countyName = "ST. " + countyName.substr(5);
                    }
                    countyName += " COUNTY";
                }
                if (item.story_link == 'no') {
                    $(countyInfo).html('<strong>' + countyName + '</strong><br />' + item.data_total_students + ' Students<br />' + item.data_total_alumni + ' Alumni<br />' + '$' + item.economicImpact + ' Impact<br />Click For More...');
                } else { 
                    $(countyInfo).html('<strong>' + countyName + '</strong><br />' + item.data_total_students + ' Students<br />' + item.data_total_alumni + ' Alumni<br />' + '$' + item.economicImpact + 'Impact<br /><strong>Latest story:</strong><br /><img src="' + item.story_link + '" alt="story" height="75" width="110"><br />' + item.story_title + '<br />Click For More...');

                }
             });
        });

        // hide the pre-loader
        $('#preloader').animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 1000);

         //randomly rotate through the counties
        setInterval(highlightRandomCounty, ROTATION_INTERVAL * 1000);
    });
```

Is there something that I need to enable/disable in order for this to function correctly in IE?  Perhaps some sort of .getJSON/caching issue in IE?  Any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the ***Known Issues List*** "*Internet Explorer converts relative URLs into absolute URLs. Unfortunately there are no reasonable workarounds to this problem.*" Maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: I am using HTML and Jquery, along with the XML file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, everyone.  So far, nothing seems to fix the problem.  I uploaded a copy of all of the code to another web host, and it works fine in IE.  So, there must be something in my current web host that affects JSON/Jquery in a way that IE does not like?  I am still pulling my hair out with this, so any other suggestions are greatly appreciated. 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thantos - I've updated my answer below, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few known issues with IE treating all ajax request as regular web requests. So things get cached.

You can try....

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$.getJSON("/MyQueryUrl",
   function(data) {
     // do stuff with callback data
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
   });
```

Also, if you are using ASP.NET
 on the server side set cacheability

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's totally random, my gut reaction is that IE is failing to set up the hover correctly when the image hasn't loaded yet. Try moving your hover setup into the load() callback function, after you set width and height.

EDIT: Based on your new information, I recommend changing the top line of your script to end in ".json" instead of ".js". Your current web host may (*correctly*) return your JSON response as mime-type x-javascript instead of json, which could definitely confuse IE.

Comment: After further review, it is the same counties that do not display in IE.  The random county display function will display those counties, though...It is only the hover functionality that does not seem to work with them.